# replacing a text inside clipboard which contains html formatted string in C#

Tags: c#, html, string, replace

What I want to do is to replace a part of the text inside the clipboard, but the problem is it is html formatted text and I am unable to modify its content using the below given code in C#. Any solutions?

Steps to replicate my doing:

1- copy an entry from cambridge advanced learner dictionary 4 to clipboard OR any other html formatted text to clipboard

2- Use these C# codes in a windows forms application to modify and replace text while keeping its html formatting:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string myStr = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
            myStr.Replace("Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 4th Edition", "******************************");
            Clipboard.SetText(myStr,TextDataFormat.Html);

        }
```

But it seems that it does not work at all!

NOTE: I want to keep the html formatting, I don't want to strip string from its html formatting.

---

I used Regex and it seems to work when I use:

```
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 4th Edition", "");
```

but when I want to use:

```
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 4th Edition<br /><br />", "");
```

it does not work! any solutions to remove those html tags: `<br /><br />`
?

Comment: You can replace the content with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex solved the problem to some extent like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string myStr = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
            myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 4th Edition", "");

            Clipboard.SetText(myStr,TextDataFormat.Html);

        }
```

but still unable to remove HTML tags like `<br /><br />` from clipboard.

Comment: There nothing regex specific in this replace statement (it does not contain a regular expression).

Comment: using:             myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 4th Edition<br /><br />", "");

Answer (score 0):

You must format the text in a special [HTML Clipboard Format (link to description)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It looks like this (working example unlike the exmaple given in the link, which has wrong Start- and End- numbers):

```html
Version:1.0
StartHTML:00085
EndHTML:00287
StartFragment:00105
EndFragment:00269
<!--StartFragment--><HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY>YOUR <B>HTML FORMATTED</B> TEXT GOES HERE!</BODY></HTML><!--EndFragment-->
```

Also make sure to fill in the right Start- and End- numbers in the top section. More specifically, you must adapt `EndHTML`, `EndFragment` and `EndSelection` to reflect the change in the length of your text. Replacing alone won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML input can be arbitrary, here are the steps I suggest:

1. Assuming you have a way to detect that the clipboard content is indeed in HTML, tidy it using a C# library of your choice (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002346/c-sharp-version-of-html-tidy)). This will allow the app to work with content which is "sanitized", i.e., HTML breaks such as `<br>` and `<br />` below will be *tidied* to standard `<br/>` which you can then omit or replace.
2. Instead of using "one-off" RegEx replacement like the one you have for handing HTML breaks, try to make your code a bit more flexible by anticipating future additions to the list of offending HTML elements you need to replace, i.e., use groups (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351031/regex-replace-multiple-groups)). You will then be able to provide the user of your forms app a way to configure which elements to omit.